# Getting unknown property on Model attribute in Yii2-advanced

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I am having a model class in my Yii2-advanced application which was having some attributes.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['SESSION_TITLE', 'SESSION_DESCRIPTION', 'TRAINER_ID'], 'required'],
        [['TRAINER_ID','IS_ACTIVE', 'IS_DELETED'], 'integer'],
    ];
}
```

Now, I need to add an attribute `TNI_NUMBER` in model which I already have added in database table with similar spellings. After adding in model.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['SESSION_TITLE', 'SESSION_DESCRIPTION', 'TRAINER_ID'], 'required'],
        [['TRAINER_ID','TNI_NUMBER' ,'IS_ACTIVE', 'IS_DELETED'], 'integer'],
    ];
}
```

The form is showing `Getting Unknown Property` on that specific attribute, on loading the form right after adding this attribute. Note that the data type of attribute in model and in database is not an issue. And the database connection array has set `'enableSchemaCache' => true` in it and it can't be set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yii::$app->cache->flush();
```

This worked for me, added it before calling model class in controller action.

NOTE: this is for one-time usage only, once page refreshed after adding this line, do remember to comment or remove it.

Comment: That's not best solution. This will flush all cache when you access that action which pretty much makes cache useless. Instead you should simply run `yii cache/flush-schema` command when you change DB structure.

Comment: What's the difference? Plus I used it for once only, moreover the application is in development mode on localhost, so what's the big deal?

Comment: If you only add it, call action and remove it right after that, than it's ok. But it's easy to forget about it and it can get into production. So why take risks when there is cli command for that?
Also your answer doesn't mention using it only once and removing it right after that.

Comment: Yes, this was for one-time usage. Edited the answer with the note. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the column was missing in the db table. When I ran migrations it fixed itself.

Answer (score -2):

you need to refresh database schema

```php
Yii::$app->db->schema->refresh();
```

You only need to run this once

or

you can set 'enableSchemaCache' to false